# Complex Analysis Textbook using Fluid Dynamics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, complex-numbers

This is a literature request.  I remember being told of a Complex Analysis textbook that teaches the Cauchy-Riemann equations and Potential Theory using Fluid Dynamics.  Does anyone know who the author might be?

Comment: This isn't the normal way we handle resource recommendation requests; typically these questions ask for books in a given subject. [tag:specific-reference] may apply, but not sure.

Comment: could be i could remove this question or ask a more detailed

Comment: I don't think it's off topic as is, but the tags probably should be swapped out. If you could add other details about the book, it might help others figure it out also.